# Facebook Sharer PHP application redirect

Tags: facebook, social-networking

Following a successful share on Facebook with URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cars.com
```

a user is redirected to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_
```

How can we set the redirect_uri without creating a facebook application?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog contains no references to https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php

Comment: There's no references, because sharer.php is a legacy script, not supported officially any more. // Don't be scared, creating apps doesn't hurt. So overcome your fears, and use the Share Dialog.

Comment: Furher explained, Facebook wouldn't allow me to create a separate account in order to create an application id, utilizing my phone number as the 2nd verification because it is already inked.   .  I will add administrators through [developers.facebook.com](http://www.developers.facebook.com)

Comment: You’re not supposed to create multiple accounts for app development. You are only allowed to have one personal account, and it must be a “real” one (for example using a fake name can easily get the account blocked, and then you’ll have trouble getting access to your app back.)

Comment: The purpose was to separate work account from personal facebook account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an application id APP_ID by navigating to [developers.facebook.com](http://www.developers.facebook.com).
2. Create GET Request.  Ex: request to developers.facebook.com redirecting to www.aol.com

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=APP_ID&display=page&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aol.com